# I cant make my multiple contact add form dynamic due to its field ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Currently i am developing functionality where i am adding contact form for multiple clients .

i have added multiple forms using jquery append method where i use html of same view page to add same form multiple times , but the problem is i cant make this form ids dynamic as i am using same html block to add multiple forms , and i can not write that html block in jquery please help.

code:

```
html : 


    <!-- plus button from where i add another contact form -->
               <span  id="add_btn_div">
                  <button class="btn mr-lft-5" type="button" name="add_new_contact" id="add_new_contact" ><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
               </span>
             <!-- plus button code ends here  -->  


            <!-- span where html block gets appended after click on plus button -->
        <span  id="contact_group">
        </span>
            <!-- span ends here  ends here -->

<!-- contact form html block which get appended in above span after click on plus button -->
           <span id="add_contact_html" style="display:none;">
  <div class="">
    <hr />
      <div class="companyWrap">
          <h3></h3>
              <div class="control-group">
              <div class="controls">
                <label class="control-label text-left">Contact Name: </label>
                <input class="span10" type="text" id="ContactName" name="ContactName[]" placeholder="Type Contact Name" required maxlength="30" pattern="<?php echo TEXT_PATTERN ?>" title="<?php echo TEXT_MESSAGE ?>">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <div class="controls">
                <label class="control-label text-left">Address: </label>
                <textarea class="span10" rows="3"  id="ContactAddress" name="ContactAddress[]" maxlength="250" pattern="<?php echo TEXT_PATTERN ?>" title="<?php echo TEXT_MESSAGE ?>"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <div class="controls">
                <label class="control-label text-left">Email ID:</label>
                <input class="span10" type="email" id="Email" name="Email[]" placeholder="Email ID" required  maxlength="100" pattern="<?php echo EMAIL_PATTERN ?>+" title="<?php echo EMAIL_MESSAGE ?>">
              </div>
            </div>

             <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                  <label class="control-label text-left">User Name:</label>
                 <input type="text" placeholder="Type User Name" id="UserName" name="UserName[]" class="span10" pattern="<?php echo TEXT_PATTERN ?>+" title="<?php echo TEXT_MESSAGE ?>" onkeyup="funAutoSuggestName('UserName','ContactName','client')" required  maxlength="30">
                </div>
              </div>    


             <div class="control-group" id="suggestedName" >
                <div class="controls">
                     <label class="control-label text-left">&nbsp;</label>
                     <div style="width:80%;float:left;margin:5px;" id="suggested_txt">
                    </div>
               </div>
             </div> 



            <div class="control-group">
              <div class="controls">
                <label class="control-label text-left">Mobile Number:</label>
                <input class="span3 mr-botom-10" type="tel" id="MobileNumber1_dyn" name="MobileNumber1[]" maxlength="3" onkeydown="phoneNumberValidate('MobileNumber1',3,'MobileNumber2')"  pattern="<?php echo NUMBER_PATTERN_3_DIG; ?>" title="<?php echo NUMBER_PATTERN_3_MSG; ?>">
                <input class="span3 mr-botom-10" type="tel" id="MobileNumber2_dyn" name="MobileNumber2[]" maxlength="3" onkeydown="phoneNumberValidate('MobileNumber2',3,'MobileNumber3')"  pattern="<?php echo NUMBER_PATTERN_3_DIG; ?>" title="<?php echo NUMBER_PATTERN_3_MSG; ?>">
                <input class="span4  mr-botom-10" type="tel" id="MobileNumber3_dyn"  name="MobileNumber3[]" maxlength="4" onkeydown="phoneNumberValidate('MobileNumber3',4,'')" pattern="<?php echo NUMBER_PATTERN_4_DIG; ?>" title="<?php echo NUMBER_PATTERN_4_MSG; ?>">

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <div class="controls">
                <label class="control-label text-left">Office Number:</label>
                <input class="span3 mr-botom-10" type="tel" id="PhoneNumber1_dyn" name="PhoneNumber1[]" maxlength="3" onkeydown="phoneNumberValidate('PhoneNumber1',3,'PhoneNumber2')">
                <input class="span3 mr-botom-10" type="tel" id="PhoneNumber2_dyn" name="PhoneNumber2[]" maxlength="3" onkeydown="phoneNumberValidate('PhoneNumber2',3,'PhoneNumber3')">
                <input class="span4  mr-botom-10" type="tel" id="PhoneNumber3_dyn" name="PhoneNumber3[]" maxlength="4" onkeydown="phoneNumberValidate('PhoneNumber3',4,'')">
               <!-- code to add dynamic contacts -->

                <button class="btn remove_client_contact" type="button" name="remove_client_contact[]"  lang="1"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>

               <!-- code to add dynamic contacts ends here -->
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </span>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#add_new_contact").click(function () 
 {
    var divObj = $('#contact_group');
    var firstHtml  = $('#add_contact_html').html();
    /* html block */
    divObj.append(firstHtml);

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any form IDs. Are you talking about the IDs of the `input`s and `textarea`s? If so, you can change the IDs if you cloned the elements instead of copying the HTML. For example, you can append a number to the end of every ID...

```
var i = 1;
$("#add_new_contact").click(function () {
    var cloned = $('#add_contact_html > div').clone();
    cloned.find("input, textarea").each(function () {
        $input = $(this);
        $input.attr("id", $input.attr("id") + i);
    });
    cloned.appendTo('#contact_group');

    i += 1;
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/r4q97/